# Difference between Single statement transaction and multistatement transaction in real life scenerio for Marklogic

Tags: transactions, marklogic

I am studying the Single statement transaction and multi-statement transaction in MarkLogic Server. Except the difference of explicit commit in multi-statement, what are other differences. I mean what are the possible use cases in which one is preferred over other?

Until now, for two transaction T1 and T2 where I need the result of one transaction in the subsequent transaction I always used `xdmp:eval()` for T1 as well as T2 and specify `<database>` as `"different-transaction"` for both T1 and T2.

What would say this as single statement or multi-statement transaction?

Answer (score 0):

This question seems a bit open-ended, but the docs have some discussion: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/transactions#id_68542

Answer (score 0):

Most common use for transactions is doing multiple updates with some user or machine interaction in between. You could commit each individual update, but for sake of consistency you sometimes would like to do a collective commit/rollback of these updates. That is when you need transactions that can span across multiple requests/statements.

You are using different-transaction, so evals really are running in a different transaction. Setting transaction-mode won't influence that, you just need to be more carefull about commit. Actually, all mentioned examples in the doc mblakele is referring too, don't span across statements.

If you really want to span across multiple statements/requests, you need to create the transaction yourself, and pass that id around. There are two undocumented features that you can use for this: `xdmp:transaction-create`, which takes no params, and the `transaction-id` option of eval, which takes the id returned by transaction-create.

Note though, that statements within transaction are executed synchronized, so I guess you need to create the transaction within an eval too, just to prevent the statement invoking eval from blocking the eval statements, causing a dead-lock..

HTH!